# WCF IPC using NamedPipes freaks out when 2 processes attempt to talk to each other on different pipes at the same time

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, ipc, named-pipes

I am using WCF and NamedPipes for InterProcess communication.

Each process listens on a unique named pipe easily discoverable by other processes.

The problem i am getting has to do with 2 processes trying to talk to each other at almost the same time. I assume on different pipes but who knows what goes on with WCF...

Essentially the flow is this : **process 1 calls a process 2 method on pipe 2 at almost the same time that process 2 calls a process 1 method on pipe 1**. When this happens i keep getting TimeoutExceptions on my ICommunicationObject.Close() call.

I have tried NamedPipes and NetTcp and both have the same problem. BasicHttp on the other hand does not...Works fine but i should not have to use BasicHttp for IPC on the same machine.

Another important info. If i enqueue my reply call using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() then it works.
It looks like enqueuing the next call gives WCF time to complete the first call before starting the next call back. But why does that even matter when the processes are communicating ON DIFFERENT PIPES??

Any input is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This a classic deadlock situation. Both sides post work on each other's UIThread and both are waiting for the other blocked side to reply.
I switched the callers to instead use Tasks and Dispatch the remote calls on a background thread and all is fine.